# Shell script tar specific files with retention period

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to Unix Shell script. I need to keep file for retention period of one month and archive other.

Example:

File format: WE20160225.log (20160225 YYYYMMDD)

Say in the directory /oracle/Sales has 3 files:

WE20160130.log

WE20151201.log

WE20151109.log

I need to tar.gz the WE20151201.log and WE20151109.log

But not WE20160130.log because the file is less than one month from now. How can I do this? (probably need to substring the filename)

I'm able to change directory but don't know what to do next. My logic is loop through the file and substring the date from file and check with current date

**I need to use the filename date, not the file modification date.**

```
SALES_DIR="/oracle/sales/"
cd $SALES_DIR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `for` loop:

```
curr=$(date '+%s')
for file in WE*.log; do
   f="${file%.*}"
   ts=$(date -d "${f:2}" '+%s')
   (( (curr - ts) > 30*86400 )) && echo "$file"
done | tar cvzf backup.tgz -T-
```

Basically we are getting current date-time in unix seconds and then extracting date from file and finding it's EPOCH (unix ts) value using `date`.

Finally we are comparing difference of 2 timestamps with `30*86400` (30 days) and printing the filename. Whole thing is piped to a `tar` command to create a tar zipped file.

Comment: Using `-T` option, `tar` can read the source filenames from a file and `-T-` makes it read from `STDIN` since we are printing filenames in the `for` loop

Comment: oh do you mean you pipe the whole thing(file names that match) and we get the whole thing from STDIN and then tar.gz it?

Comment: That's right, you can see I am using `| tar cvzf backup.tgz -T-` after `done`. Which makes `tar` read all the source files from the `for loop`

Comment: alright, didn't know i can pipe the whole output from the for loop, thank you... :)

Answer (score 2):

Probably something along those lines:

```
list=`ls *.log`

limit=`date --date 'Last Month' +%Y%m%d`

for filename in $list
  do
    if [ ${filename:2:8} -lt $limit ]
      then
        tar -czf "$filename.tar.gz" $filename
      fi
  done;
```

Comment: your script will produce 2 tar.gz file, but i just only want 1 tar.gz, thanks btw